# SUM columns inline using GROUP BY

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the next table in Access:

```
ID  |   Name  |  Dog    |   Cat   |
===================================
1   | A       |   100   |   0     |
1   | B       |   0     |   100   |
1   | C       |   50    |   0     |
2   | A       |   100   |   0     |
2   | B       |   3     |   100   |
2   | C       |   3     |   50    |
```

By a query I need it to be shown like this:

```
ID  |   Name  |  Dog    |   Cat   |
===================================
1   | A       |   100   |   0     |
1   | B       |   0     |   100   |
1   | C       |   50    |   0     |
1   | TOTAL   |   50    |   0     |
2   | A       |   100   |   0     |
2   | B       |   0     |   100   |
2   | C       |   0     |   50    |
2   | TOTAL   |   0     |   -50   |
```

As you can see, first I sum the columns Dog and Cat, after this I sum Dog - Cat, If that value is positive goes to the column Dog, if negative goes to the column Cat. I'm new with this, I've checked similar questions, But I would like to see the simplest way to deal with this. Thanks!

By far I have:

```
SELECT ID, Name, Dog, Cat
FROM Table
UNION 
SELECT ID, 'Total', SUM(Dog), SUM(Cat)
FROM Table
GROUP BY ID
```

And I've got this:

```
ID  |   Name  |  Sum(Dog)|   Sum(Cat)|
======================================
1   | A       |   100    |   0       |
1   | B       |   0      |   100     |
1   | C       |   50     |   0       |
1   | TOTAL   |   150    |   100     |
2   | A       |   100    |   0       |
2   | B       |   0      |   100     |
2   | C       |   0      |   50      |
2   | TOTAL   |   100    |   150     |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use `union all` and `order by`.  In MS Access, I think this would be:

```
SELECT ID, Name, SUM(Dog), Sum(Cat)
FROM Table
GROUP BY ID, Name
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, "Total", SUM(Dog), Sum(Cat)
FROM Table
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY IIF(Name = "Total", 1, 0), Name
```

You can try this with a subquery:

```
SELECT name, name, num_dogs, num_cats
FROM (SELECT ID, Name, SUM(Dog) as num_dogs, Sum(Cat) as num_cats, 1 as ord
      FROM Table
      GROUP BY ID, Name
      UNION ALL
      SELECT ID, "Total", SUM(Dog), Sum(Cat), 0 as ord
      FROM Table
      GROUP BY ID
     ) as t
ORDER BY ord, Name
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm having conflicts with the ORDER BY part, it says that includes fields that are not selected in the query. In an ORDER BY expression it only can be included fields in the first query